# This script works as I want to, but its ugly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which I worked hard on, but it is pretty ugly but it works. It can check all check boxes (with .select-all), and if one of those check boxes (.chk-box) is unchecked, the .select-all will also become unchecked. Moreover the .select-all will also hide a div (.hidethis). I am in the learning state, so if someone (if easy) can show me a nicer code with this functionality it is very welcome! It can learn me a alot!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("document").ready(function()
        {
            if($(".select-all").is(":checked"))    
            {               
                $(".hidethis").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $(".hidethis").show();
            }
        });

        $(".select-all").change(function () 
        {
            if (this.checked)   
            {               
                $(".chk-box").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
                $(".hidethis").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $(".chk-box").removeAttr("checked");
                $(".hidethis").show();
            }   
        });

        $(".chk-box").change(function ()
        {
            if($(".chk-box").length == $(".chk-box:checked").length) 
            {
                $(".select-all").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
                $(".hidethis").hide();
            } 
            else 
            {
                $(".select-all").removeAttr("checked");
                $(".hidethis").show();
            }
        });

</script>
```

Comment: `$(".hidethis").ready()` should be `$(document).ready()`. jQuery ignores the element that you bind the `.ready()` handler to, since it only makes sense for the document.

Comment: There's only one `.select-all` checkbox, right? So just use `if($(".select-all").is(":checked"))` to test if it's checked. And in the `.change()` handler, you can just use `if (this.checked)`.

Comment: Thanks, the first two things corrected. I am not sure what you thinking about with the `.change()` handler. What should `if (this.checked)` replace?

Comment: It replaces `if ($(".select-all").length == $(".select-all:checked").length))`.

Comment: Great, got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't ugly - but `if($(".select-all").length == $(".select-all:checked").length)` isn't immediately clear on what it does (if your goal here is readability). Also, you don't need the if/else on the select-all change, since you always want to set all chk-boxes to whatever the value of select-all is anyway.

[Here's a fiddle I made](https://jsfiddle.net/88oukwbq/) that's a bit cleaner. I just run a loop over all the check boxes to see if they are all set or not. The check all handler just applies its value to all check boxes. The hide-all can just be handled in those two events.

The JS:

```
$(".check").on("change", function() {
    var allChecked = true;
    $(".check").each(function(i) {
        allChecked = allChecked && $(this).prop("checked");
    });
    $(".check-all").prop("checked", allChecked);

    allChecked ? $(".hidethis").hide() : $(".hidethis").show();
});

$(".check-all").on("change", function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
    $(".check").prop("checked", checked);

    checked ? $(".hidethis").hide() : $(".hidethis").show();
});
```

Comment: A lot cleaner, thanks! And your comments before the code make sense to me (now) :)

Comment: This is nice and clean one other suggestion I would make is to cache your selectors in variables `var $check = $(".check")`, `var $checkAll = $(".check-all")`, `var $hidethis = $(".hidethis")` 

Not that it is one hundred percent necessary for such a small sample size but its does save some typing and DOM look ups and Object creation each time it runs the loop it searches the DOM to find all of `$(".check")` etc.

Comment: @HansPede, T.B. I think a few things can be smoothed even more: https://jsfiddle.net/dhrx729b/